# Manually firing off signal event?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, multipeer-connectivity, peer

I'm wondering if there is a way to manually cause a simplepeer Peer object to fire of the signal data event that does of when a initiating peer is created.

More precisely what I want to do is to create Peer objects with the initiator property set to false and then manually turn them into initiating peers.

Is this possible or should I look elsewhere?

Update 1:

I tried to create a non initiating peers and then set initiator to true via function but that did not trigger the signal event.

so basically this:

```
let p = new SimplePeer();
p.on('signal', function (data) {

  console.log('SIGNAL', JSON.stringify(data))
});

const turnOn = function () {
  p.initiator = true; 
};

turnOn();
```

*This is not the actual code, just the parts that have to do with the question.

Comment: can you share your attempt?

Comment: See the description, I just added a more detailed explanation.

Comment: are you using [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer)?

Comment: yes, I mention it in the first line of the question.